# Add currency fields to get a subtotal, then add other values but only if the relevant checkbox is checked

Tags: c#

I have some currency fields which need to be added together. However, some of them have a checkbox nearby. If this is ticked, the field is added to the subtotal, if not, nothing is added.

I'm currently using the code below, which works, but doesn't seem very elegant or easy to maintain. I'm sure there is an easier way but I'm struggling to think of any other methods to use. There will be more checkboxes added later on, which will only lengthen the code. The below example is for two checkboxes.

```
decimal ditem1Cost = 0;
bool item1Checked = false;
if (Item1RateYN.Checked) {
    if (decimal.TryParse(item1Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem1Cost))
        item1Checked = true;
}

decimal ditem2Cost = 0;
bool item2Checked = false;
if (Item2RateYN.Checked) {
    if (decimal.TryParse(item2Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem2Cost))
        item2Checked = true;
}
//Add up some values which are always part of the subtotal
decimal subtotals = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7 + val8;

//Only add the ones which are near the checkboxes, if the checkbox is checked
subtotals = item1Checked ? subtotals + ditem1Cost : subtotals;
subtotals = item2Checked ? subtotals + ditem2Cost : subtotals;
```

Comment: `val1` to `val8`? No arrays? You've stripped your code so much that it doesn't make any sense anymore.

Comment: Not stripped, that's how it actually is. There's only ever 8 values required and I get their values from controls on the form. As long as they all parse to decimal, the function continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lot of logic that is not necessary

```
x = x + 0

decimal ditem1Cost = 0;
decimal ditem2Cost = 0;
if (Item1RateYN.Checked) 
{
    decimal.TryParse(item1Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem1Cost);
}
if (Item2RateYN.Checked) 
{
    decimal.TryParse(item2Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem2Cost);
}
//Add up some values which are always part of the subtotal
decimal subtotals = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7 + val8 
                  + ditem1Cost + ditem2Cost;
```

Comment: This looks great. I've tried it out and it seems to do the trick, with far less code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
//Add up some values which are always part of the subtotal
decimal subtotals = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7 + val8;

decimal ditem1Cost;
if (Item1RateYN.Checked) {
    decimal.TryParse(item1Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem1Cost); 
    subtotals+=ditem1Cost;
}
decimal ditem2Cost;
if (Item2RateYN.Checked) {
    decimal.TryParse(item2Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem2Cost);
    subtotals+=ditem2Cost;
}
```

Is slightly better.

If using C#7 remove decimal `ditem1Cost = 0;` and replace `decimal.TryParse(item2Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem1Cost)` with `decimal.TryParse(item2Cost.Value.ToString(), out decimal cost)`

Comment: If not using C#7 remove `= 0` (twice): out parameters are always overwritten.